# ¿Cómo usar AJAX para subir archivos pesados por partes (chunks)?

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy tratando de hacer un chunk uploader, haciendo que si un archivo pesa más de 5000bytes, lo fragmente y lo mande poco a poco a la carpeta de destino. Pero estoy atascado en una parte en la que, según la docu, debería ser así, pero el contenido que lee del archivo es 0.

```
if (isset($_FILES['file1']) /*&& $_FILES['file1']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK*/){

    // detalles del archivo
    $fileTmpPath = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file1']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file1']['type'];
    $fileNameCmps = explode(".", $fileName);
    $fileExtension = strtolower(end($fileNameCmps));

    $chunk_size = 5000;
    $upload_start = 0;

    // verificador de extensiones
    $allowedfileExtensions = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'zip', 'txt', 'xls', 'doc', 'pdf', '7z', 'mp4', 'img', 'php', 'iso');

    if (in_array($fileExtension, $allowedfileExtensions)){
      // directory in which the uploaded file will be moved
      $uploadFileDir = 'archivos_aaron_pruebas/';
      $dest_path = $uploadFileDir . $fileName;

      if($fileSize < $chunk_size){//Comprueba si tiene mas de 5MB
        
        $handle = fopen($fileName, "r");
        $fp = fopen($dest_path, "w");

        $contents = fread($dest_path, $chunk_size);
        fwrite($fp, $contents);
        $upload_start += strlen($contents);
        die('contenido leido: '.$contents.'->'.$upload_start);
        fseek($handle, $upload_start);

        fclose($handle);
        fclose($fp);

        $message = 'Archivo desfragmentado y reacoplado correctamente.';

      } else {
        if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpPath, $dest_path)){//Mueve archivo al directorio
          $message ='Archivo subido correctamente.';
        } else {
          $message = 'Error al subir el archivo.';
        }
      }
    }
```

¿Qué es lo que tengo mal? Nunca llega a escribir nada....

---

**[EDIT]**

Acabo de cambiar el js con la pregunta de ejemplo que me puso @Triby, pero solo ha conseguido que me haga más lío. Ahora ni siquiera se cómo funciona:

Declaré variables globales, dentro de las funciones las asigné los valores.
Iteré todos los files que meto en los input, esto funciona correctamente.
Cuando, dentro de la función `selectFile` llego a la parte de las request, SI COMENTO LA PARTE DE ABAJO, no funciona, no se mandan los eventos. Pero si no la comento, me sube los archivos VACÍOS.

```
//editado
```

Y en el PHP tengo lo siguiente:

```
$target_path = 'archivos_aaron_pruebas/';
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
$size = $_FILES['file1']['size'];
$name = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$sports = $_GET['file'];
$part =(string)$_GET['num'];
//$part = split("/\=/", $part);
$target_file = $target_path .$part. $sports;


// Open temp file
$out = fopen($target_file, "wb");

if ( $out ) {
    // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
    $in = fopen($tmp_name, "rb");
    if ( $in ) {
        while ( $buff = fread( $in, 1048576 ) ) {
            fwrite($out, $buff);
        }   
    }
    fclose($in);
    fclose($out);
}
```

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal? No entiendo nada ya.

---

**[EDIT 2]**

Ya he conseguido hacer, gracias a respirar profundamente una hora, que se suba el primer 1MB del archivo que mande (pruebo con uno de 7.3MB).

A la hora de subirlo, este entra en bucle y comienza a hacer chunks del mismo archivo una y otra y otra vez. Cuando llega a los 6MB, para, y vuelve a empezar de 0 (ahí el bucle), pero no se en qué punto para por mi error:

```
var x, xhr, chunk, txt, start, part, BYTES_PER_CHUNK, end;

function selectFile(){
    let file = _("file1");

    if('files' in file){
        for(let i=0;i < file.files.length;i++){
            x = file.files[i];
            start = 0;
            part = 0;
            BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1048576;

            //despliegue del temp
            txt = createElement();
            document.body.append(txt);

            //logs
            if ('name' in x) {
                txt.getElementsByClassName('txt_file_name')[0].innerHTML = '<strong>Name:</strong> '+x.name;
            }
            if ('size' in x) {
                txt.getElementsByClassName('txt_file_size')[0].innerHTML = '<strong>Size:</strong> '+x.size;
            }
    
            let bar = txt.getElementsByClassName('progressBar')[0];

            //request
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress",(event)=>{uploadProgress(event, bar)}, false);
            xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
            xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
            xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

            uploadFile(x, part);
        }
    }
}

function uploadFile(chunkFile, part){
    xhr.open("POST", "upload.php"+"?"+"file="+x.name+"&num=" + part);
    //xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control','no-cache');
    let fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file1", chunkFile);
    xhr.send(fd);
    return;
}

function uploadComplete(evt) {
    start = 0;
    end = BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
    part = 0;
    while( start < x.size ) {
        console.log(start);
        chunk = x.slice(start, end);
        uploadFile(chunk, part);
        start = end;
        end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
        part++;
    }
}

function uploadProgress(event, bar) {
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + event.total;
    let percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    bar.value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";
}

function uploadFailed(event) {
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload failed";
}
  
function uploadCanceled(event) {
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload canceled";
}

function createElement(){
    let dv = document.createElement('div');
        dv.setAttribute('class', 'demo');
    let p1 = document.createElement('p');
        p1.setAttribute('class', 'txt_file_name');
    let p2 = document.createElement('p');
        p2.setAttribute('class', 'txt_file_size');
    let pr = document.createElement('progress');
        pr.setAttribute('class', 'progressBar');
        pr.setAttribute('value', '0');
        pr.setAttribute('max', '100');
  
        dv.append(p1);
        dv.append(p2);
        dv.append(pr);
  
    return dv;
  }

function _(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el);
  }
```

Comment: El problema es que PHP solo recibe archivos completos, no tiene utilidad fragmentar un archivo que ya se subió, eso lo tienes que hacer desde el cliente y. cuando finalice el envío de todas las partes, las **unes en PHP** para tener el archivo completo.

Comment: Podrías comenzar revisando [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792538/javascript-large-file-uploader) (en inglés).

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar, pero al final me hago más lio aun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo varios problemas aquí:

- De acuerdo a preguntas anteriores, tienes ya un script para subida múltiple de archivos y estás tratando de implementar esta solución junto con lo anterior
- Con subidas múltiples no conviene tener variables globales para controlar la subida de archivos, en cuanto termine la primera petición, se van a sobrescribir esas variables y el resultado va a ser completamente impredecible
- No es que la subida de archivos se reinicie, una parte tiene que ver con el punto anterior y otra con que tienes un ciclo para subir cada *chunk*, pero deberías esperar a que se complete una para subir la siguiente, escuchando el evento `load`

### Posible solución

- Analiza si el archivo pesa más de lo permitido para subirlo por partes o usar las funciones que ya tienes cuando se trate de archivos pequeños
- Encapsula la subida del archivo en una función donde puedas crear un contexto aparte, teniendo propiedades y métodos que no se van a mezclar con otros
- Usa otro script de PHP para subir las partes y unirlas cuando se haya recibido el archivo completo

```
// Definir constantes para valores necesarios
const IS_LARGE_FILE = 3145728;   // Subir por partes si pesa más de 3MB
const BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1048576; // Tamaño de cada parte a subir: 1MB

// Encapsular subida de cada archivo en una función
// Aunque podría ser una clase
const uploadLargeFiles = function(file) {
    // ***** Métodos *****
    this.uploadProgress = function(e) {
        // Progreso de la parte actual
        let progress = parseInt(e.total / e.loaded * 100);
        console.log(`Subiendo archivo ${this.file.name} (${this.part}) ${progress}%`);
    };
    this.uploadError = function(e) {
        console.log('Error subiendo parte');
    };
    // Partir archivo
    this.getChunk = function() {
        // Obtener inicio del chunk actual
        let start = (this.part) * BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
        // Actualizar parte que se está procesando
        this.part ++;
        if(start > this.file.size) {
            // Ya se envió el archivo completo, no deberíamos haber entrado aquí
            return false;
        }
        // Crear y devolver chunk
        return = this.file.slice(start, BYTES_PER_CHUNK);
    };
    this.uploadChunk = function(e) {
        if(this.part >= this.parts) {
            // Ya se terminó de subir el archivo
            return;
        }
        // Si no es el inicio de la primera parte, hay un evento válido
        if(e) {
            console.log(`Archivo ${this.file.name}, parte ${this.part} subido correctamente.`);
        }
        // Obtener parte a subir
        let chunk = this.getChunk();
        // Solo por evitar cualquier error, asegurar que hay una parte para subir
        if(chunk !== false) {
            // Inicializar petición
            this.xhr.open("POST", "uploadChunks.php");
            this.xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control','no-cache');
            // Agregar datos a petición
            let data = new FormData();
            data.append('chunk', chunk);  // Debe llegar en $_FILES
            data.append('parts', this.parts); // Total de partes a subir
            data.append('part', this.part); // Parte actual
            // Subir este chunk
            this.xhr.send(data);
        }
    };
    // ***** Propiedades e inicialización
    // Guardar referencia al archivo que se va a subir
    this.file = file;
    // Saber cuántas partes se van a enviar
    this.parts = ceil(file.size / BYTES_PER_CHUNK);
    this.part = 0;
    console.log(`El archivo ${this.file.name} se va a subir en ${this.parts} partes`);
    // Inicializar objeto para peticiones AJAX
    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Escuchar eventos enlazando el contexto actual: .bind(this)
    this.xhr.addEventListener('progress', this.uploadProgress.bind(this));
    this.xhr.addEventListener('error', this.uploadError.bind(this));
    this.xhr.addEventListener('abort', this.uploadError.bind(this));
    // Subir otra parte solo hasta que se termine de subir la anterior
    this.xhr.addEventListener('load', this.uploadChunk.bind(this));
    // Comenzar a subir parte 1
    this.uploadChunk();
};

// Tu función actual para subir múltiples archivos
function selectFile() {
    // Obtener lista de archivos
    let files = document.querySelector('#file1');
    // Una lista de archivos no se puede recorrer con forEach
    // Por eso se usa Array.from()
    Array.from(files.files).forEach(file => {
        if(file.size >= IS_LARGE_FILE) {
            // El archivo es mayor de lo permitido
            // Subir por partes
            uploadLargeFiles(file);
        } else {
            // Subir normalmente
            // Con las funciones que ya tienes
        }
    });
}
```

Un nuevo script PHP para recibir las partes.

uploadChunks.php

```
<?php
// Asignar archivo solo si está en $_FILES y se subió correctamente
$chunk = (isset($_FILES['chunk']) && $_FILES['chunk']['error'] == 0) ? $_FILES['chunk'] : false;
// Obtener total de partes y parte actual
$parts = (isset($_POST['parts'])) ? intval($_POST['parts']) : 0;
$part = (isset($_POST['part'])) ? intval($_POST['part']) : 0;

// Validar que hay archivo y los valores de partes son adecuados
if($chunk === false || $parts <=0 || $part <= 0) {
    // Algo falló
    exit('Error al subir chunk');
}
// Subir a un directorio temporal, debes verificar que existe, es accesible y tiene permisos de escritura
$dir = './chunks';
// Tomar nombre original del archivo
$name = $chunk['name'];

// Mover archivo (parte) a directorio temporal, agregando número de parte al nombre
// Ejemplos: ./chunks/nombre-original.png-1, ./chunks/nombre-original.png-2, ./chunks/nombre-original.png-3
if(!move_uploaded_file($chunk['tmp_name'], "$dir/$name-$part")) {
    // Algo falló, probablemente el directorio no existe o no tiene permisos de escritura
    exit('Error moviendo archivo a directorio temporal');
}

// ¿Ya se subieron todas las partes?
if($part == $parts) {
    // Mover a directorio final
    $finalDir = './uploads';
    // Crear archivo nuevo con el nombre original
    $finalFile = fopen("$finalDir/$name", 'w');
    // Recorrer partes para agregar a archivo
    for($i = 1; $i <= $parts; $i++) {
        $bytes = filesize("$dir/$name-$i");
        // Abrir parte, leer y cerrar
        $filePart = fopen("$dir/$name-$i", 'rb');
        $contenido = fread($filePart, $bytes);
        fclose($filePart);
        // Eliminar archivo, ya no lo necesitas
        unlink("$dir/$name-$i");
        // Agregar esta parte al archivo
        fwrite($finalFile, $bytes);
    }
    // Cerrar archivo
    fclose($finalFile);
    exit('Archivo final creado correctamente');
}
echo 'Parte subida correctamente';
```

### Notas importantes

- Esta respuesta está basada en las respuestas de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792538/javascript-large-file-uploader) de SO en inglés
- No copies y pegues el código, es probable que no funcione porque no lo probé; revisa los comentarios y trata de entender lo que hace cada cosa; solo entonces intégralo en tu proyecto y comienza a realizar las pruebas correspondientes
- Deberás adaptar para mostrar el progreso de las partes subidas
- En PHP debes validar que los directorios involucrados existan, tengan permisos de escritura y las rutas sean correctas
- Sería conveniente agregar alguna validación adicional cuando un archivo existe, por si quieres sobrescribir o renombrar para guardar ambos

Answer (score -1):

Fread() es una función de lectura de archivos, en lugar de $dest_path deberias usar $filename en su primer argumento.

Un saludo.