# Problema de lógica

Tags: javascript, lógica

He creado un JS que manda los archivos de un formulario a un PHP para que lo mande a una carpeta.
En dicho JS, si el archivo seleccionado pesa más de 1MB, lo divide en trozos de lo mismo, 1MB y los manda poco a poco.

Necesito poder colocar BIEN la barra de progreso para que se complete al haber completado TODOS los eventos.

Ejemplo: Si mando un archivo de 7MB, mandará 7 miniarchivos, con lo cual, serían 7 eventos, que cuando se completase cada uno, la barra de progreso aumentaría un x% dependiendo del número de miniarchivos que se manden, en este caso 14.28%, mas o menos.

El problema está en la lógica de la estructura del código, que no doy con ello para poder poner la estructura tal y como he querido definir arriba. Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
var chunk, txt, start, part, BYTES_PER_CHUNK, end;

function selectFile(){
    let file = _("file1");

    if('files' in file){
        for(let i=0;i < file.files.length;i++){
            let x = file.files[i];
            start = 0;
            part = 0;
            BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1048576;

            //despliegue del temp
            txt = createElement();
            document.body.append(txt);

            //logs
            if ('name' in x) {
                txt.getElementsByClassName('txt_file_name')[0].innerHTML = '<strong>Name:</strong> '+x.name;
            }
            if ('size' in x) {
                txt.getElementsByClassName('txt_file_size')[0].innerHTML = '<strong>Size:</strong> '+x.size;
            }            

            uploadComplete(x);
        }
    }
}

function uploadFile(chunkFile, part, x){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let bar = txt.getElementsByClassName('progressBar')[0];
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress",(event)=>{uploadProgress(event, bar, x)}, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
    xhr.open("POST", "upload.php"+"?"+"file="+x.name+"&num=" + part);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control','no-cache');
    let fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file1", chunkFile);
    xhr.send(fd);
    return;
}

function uploadComplete(x) {
    let pol =[];
    start = 0;
    end = BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
    part = 0;
    while( start < x.size ) {
        chunk = x.slice(start, end);
        console.log(start);
        uploadFile(chunk, part, x);
        start = end;
        end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
        part++;
        pol.push({part:part,start:start,end:end});
    }
    console.log(pol);
}

function uploadProgress(event, bar, x) {
    //let total_size = x.size;
    let slice = parseInt(x.size/(1024*1024));
    


    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + event.total;
    let percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    bar.value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";
}

function uploadFailed(event) {
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload failed";
}
  
function uploadCanceled(event) {
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload canceled";
}

function createElement(){
    let dv = document.createElement('div');
        dv.setAttribute('class', 'demo');
    let p1 = document.createElement('p');
        p1.setAttribute('class', 'txt_file_name');
    let p2 = document.createElement('p');
        p2.setAttribute('class', 'txt_file_size');
    let pr = document.createElement('progress');
        pr.setAttribute('class', 'progressBar');
        pr.setAttribute('value', '0');
        pr.setAttribute('max', '100');
  
        dv.append(p1);
        dv.append(p2);
        dv.append(pr);
  
    return dv;
  }

function _(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el);
  }
```

Cada vez que subo un archivo al formulario, activa un onchange que ejecuta la función selectFile. En dicha función se ve cuántos archivos hay, los itera, crea un elemento nuevo en el DOM para ver su nombre, peso y carga, y llama a la función uploadComplete(x);

Dentro de uploadComplete, podeis ignorar el array pol ya que lo uso como control. Ahí divido cada archivo en partes de 1MB cada uno y los mando respectivamente a uploadFile().

Ahí hago la request y donde comienza, CREO, mi problema con la lógica, ya que hago los xhr.onprogress a partir del evento de cada miniarchivo.

Conclusión, que no se por dónde me pega el aire esta vez, estoy perdido.

Comment: Te doy unas recomendaciones, en vez de usar **XMLHttpRequest** utiliza la api `fetch()` nativa de js, también puedes hacer tu codigo más legible usando template strings, no puedo entender muy bien el codigo por que estoy en celular, más tarde lo veré y te ayudare

Comment: Por favor no dupliques preguntas, ya tienes [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/453816/54039) sobre el mismo tema.

Comment: no @Triby, en la anterior preguntaba cómo poder parar el bucle infinito que se me creaba, Ya esta solucionado. En esta, aunque sea en el mismo código, el problema está en la barra de progreso, que tiene que ir porcentual al evento en conjunto de subida del archivo, no a la subida de su fragmento. Es una pregunta, para mi, distinta