# La solicitud ha sido truncada con Ajax y PHP

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

Estoy enviando a una función de PHP un JSON con mas de 15 mil registros. Cuando recibo el JSON en PHP lo decodifico y los imprimo, pero la solicitud me marca **“La solicitud ha sido truncada”** y también me di cuenta de que no están llegando completos los registros.

Como puedo dar solución a ese problema ya que una vez que los reciba en la función de PHP necesito guardarlos en la base de datos.

> Anexo función de JavaScript y Ajax.

```
function uploadExcelAjax(data){

    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo base_url('ConvertFedex/uploadExcelAjax')?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {

          alert('super');

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('error');
        }
    });
  }
```

> Anexo función de PHP.

```
function uploadExcelAjax()
    {  
        if (!isset($this->session->userdata['sess_data']['id_usuario'])) {
            redirect(base_url().'Auth');
        }
        try {

            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
            print_r($data);
            echo json_encode(array("status" => true));

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            show_error($e->getMessage() . ' --- ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
        }
    }
```

> Anexo el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O de que otra forma puedo hacer el proceso para que no me marque errores y se puedan insertar los 15 mil registros en la base de datos.

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos y bonito día.

Comment: el problema no es el envio, sino el proceso
tu php esta tardando mucho en procesar eso.
busca el valor max_execution_time en tu php.ini
y ponle mas tiempo NOTA: ajax dice que se trunco por que no recibe respuesta del server.

Comment: Como sugerencia para no ponernos a adivinar, no resumas el error. Pong el fragmento del log completo en la pregunta

Comment: Hola, el max_execution_time viene en 120, cual valor seria conveniente colocar?

Comment: lo cambie por 1000 y me sigue mandando el error.

Comment: Muestra los headers de la consulta,f12

Comment: Todo lo adicional que vayas encontrando TAMBIÉN va en la pregunta. Ve a [edit] y ve añadiendo la info nueva. Por fa.

Comment: Toda solicitud http devuelve una respuesta, cuál es la respuesta de tu Ajax?

Comment: Podrías tratar de [subir el archivo por partes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/453816/54039) y hacer la inserción en base de datos hasta que se haya recibido completo.

Answer (score 0):

El lío no es que sean N registros sino que tu POST es muy grande.

En PHP, `upload_max_filesize` es el límite de cualquier archivo adjunto, mientras que `post_max_size` es el límite del body en el request (cualquier request), contando adjuntos multipart y todueso.

Revisa la configuración de tu PHP y ajusta ese `post_max_size` para que se amolde a los tamaños de mensaje que esperas. Valida con phpinfo ;)

PD. No olvides validar si en tu despliegue en producción hay algún tipo de restricción de seguridad (equipos WAF intermedios o proxies, por ejemplo), que también pueden aplicar reglas sobre el tamaño de los mensajes independientemente de los servidores.

Comment: Hola, ya cambie el valor de post_max_size=16M a post_max_size=40M y me sigue mandando el error.

Comment: De echo hasta mejor lo converti en JSON para que no pesara mucho.

Comment: O existe otra forma para poder enviar ese Json y meterlos a la BD para evitar el error de "La operacion ha sido truncada"